# startActivityResult Problem on Quick Search Box in Android?

Tags: android

How to do the startActivityResult() for the Quick Search Box? that is if i click a button in my activity. it should wake up the QSB and search. i click the suggestion button. it will return the string which is shown as a suggestion. how to do it? which intent action i have to use and how ? Any Idea?

EDIT:
i am using android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW" attribute. its reloads the current Activity.Why? which intent action i have to use and how ?

Answer (score 0):

`onSearchRequested()` will pop up the search box, but you need to [set up some infrastructure](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html) first.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i completed that what you have said in your answer. when i click my suggestion it reloads my activity. Why? i just want to drop a pin on that map.. the problem is the current Activity reloads. why?

Comment: I'd suggest you make quick search work on a blank Activity first.

Comment: it does not work. now the blank activity reloads. when we click the back butto its shows ActivityThread Exception. for that check my Previous question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848106/activitythread-exception-in-android